# Java printing timezone with full text

Tags: java, timezone

I wanted to print "20130925 050054 America/New_York" from DateFormat, I am using the following code to print that but instead it prints "20130925 050054 PDT". I am wondering, if "zzz" can be changed to print full name, "America/New_York"?

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmss zzz");
df.setTimeZone(timeZoneFromConfigFile);
String startDate=df.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
df.setTimeZone(timeZoneFromConfigFile);
String startDate = df.format(c.getTime()) + " " + c.getTimeZone().getID();
```

Not sure if you want that middle line.  It should be set in your `c` instance of `Calendar` already.

Comment: It means, there is no way in Java, it has be to done the way you answered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with zzzz instead of zzz.

I found this in the example section here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It just wouldn't print in abbreviated form, I have tried that.